# Tab width in preview window and real question/answer differs

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, code-formatting

On Stack Overflow I edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133270/how-to-illustrate-usage-of-volatile-keyword-in-c/1284007#1284007), because the code was indented by 8 spaces, which was too much too show the whole lines.
However, when I started editing, I saw the code indented only four spaces in the preview window. So the preview window looks different than the question/answer later.

I'll try to reproduce this here (hope it works):

```
code
    Indented by 4 spaces in the preview window, have a look!
/code
```

Comment: ok, it seems not to be reproduceable, here. Please refer to the linked SO-answer.